# (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) current directory for my script

Tags: php, server

i want to set the script folder into my link. here you can see, i'm using `adminPanel`, it's not into my `public_html`. it's located on `public_html/adminPanel/` everything is working, but i want to set my server directory name automatically. how i can do that?

```
$sitelink = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
        $logo = $sitelink . '/adminPanel/upload/'.$menu_image . $logo_bangla;
```

Comment: is your document root in public_html

Comment: @Jerson yes, basically public_html is root.

Comment: can you tell what is problem? your question is not clear. and add example

Comment: you see `/adminPanel/` directory, it's a folder inside `public_html`. i just want to make it automatic for any domain. if i create or change `/adminPanel/` to `/testPanel/` it will automatically detect that and replace into `/adminPanel/`. do you understand?

Comment: ok wait a minute, so in /adminPanel/ there is file example index.php?

Comment: yes, there have index.php file.

Comment: added answer, please look at below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working , I tested locally

```
 function get_abs_path() {
    $url = 'http';
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') {
        $url = 'https';
    }
    $url = "$url://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/";
    $basename = basename(__DIR__) . '/';
    return $url . $basename;    
}

echo get_abs_path();
//Output with : http://localhost/testpanel/
```

and you can use

```
$logo = get_abs_path() . 'upload/'.$menu_image . $logo_bangla;
```

Comment: if you post your answer with replacing my code, it will be better for understanding.

Comment: updated, please be polite also, and if this working please mark as answer and vote up

Comment: after adding this code, it's automatically creating `/public/` name. but i need my current folder name of my script. such `/adminPanel/`

Comment: you should put this code , in index.php in /adminPanel/ folder not outside, it can't determine the foldername.

Comment: although you can use session and save the path then retrieve it to outside of adminpanel folder

Comment: by adding `dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` solved my problem.